# How can I send a signal to a home server when the doorbell is pressed?

Tags: home-automation, doorbell

I want to attach a device that can send a signal over wireless to my server when the door bell is pressed. I'm assuming the device would tap into the wiring for the door bell, so that when pressed, the voltage triggers the relay on the wifi device to send the signal. Does anyone know of a device that can do this or lead me to a guide on how to create such a thing?

This is the start of my home automation project. I have looked at many "off-the-shelf" products and there has yet to be anything that can be a complete system with the devices I have or want to buy. A lot of it is "you need to buy this for that to work".

Comment: I'm not aware of an off the shelf component but you could use a current sensor and some sort of development board like an Arduino to detect when current flows across the wire to the doorbell, i.e. during ringing.

Answer (score 1):

Doorbells generally run on 16-20 volts AC power.
You can detect events using a microcontroller as seen here:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96136/how-to-sense-24v-ac-thermostat-with-a-5v-microcontroller

Some computers (Intel Edison, Raspberry Pi) both run linux and have GPIO inputs; otherwise you'll have to rig up a microcontroller and attach it to a home automation pc.